# Terraform: Failed to install provider: operation not permitted - when running from within a container

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform, vscode-devcontainer

From within a vscode devcontainer, i have the following tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.17.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "~>0.4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azapi" {}
```

When i do a '''terraform init''' i get the following error

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding azure/azapi versions matching "~> 0.4.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 3.17.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.17.0...
- Installing azure/azapi v0.4.0...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.17.0: chmod
│ .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.17.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.17.0_x5: operation
│ not permitted
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing azure/azapi v0.4.0: chmod
│ .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi/0.4.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azapi_v0.4.0: operation not permitted
╵
```

It looks like terraform is trying to set permissions on the provider library but failing

The user im running with in the container has root access.
Now if i do not run in a container and instead run on the host (in my case vscode on windows) - this works fine.

Does anyone know what maybe the issue here and how to resolve?

Comment: I haven't used vscode devcontainers to know their details, but is it possible that some host directory is mounted inside the countainer, and has incompatible permissions? Other than that, do you have console access inside this container? If so, show the output of `ls -l .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.17.0/linux_amd64`